# how to call checkout onepage failure with personal error message?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am making a payment gateway module, When ever the payment fails I want to display the error message I got in the response parameters, when I redirect to checkout/Onepage/failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're hitting a controller in your module, you may use the following (pseudo) code to throw an error message, and redirect to another page:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
try {
    $this->myCustomGatewayModel->authAndCapture($some, $stuff);
} catch (Vendor\Namespace\Exception\YourCustomException $e) {
    $this->getMessageManager()->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/failure');
}
```

> Keep an eye out for deprecated methods:
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Message/ManagerInterface.php
>
> The `addErrorMessage()` method will display your error (that you
>   passed in as a parameter) on the page you redirected to.
>
> Note that you may create your own custom Exception class, or you may
>   use `\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException` and either one
>   would work fine

.

> The benefit of using your own would be you can encapsulate what
>   customizations you want to display using the Throwable interface
>   `getMessage()` method. But that's just a bonus :)